# Link color stays blue after clicking until somewhere else on viewport is clicked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

In my CSS, I've tried setting font color of my navbar a elements to black using `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, and `:active` selectors but nothing is changing it.  I think my title states my problem clearly enough, but here's a link to my website, which is where I'm trying to fix it: http://students.washington.edu/jgb93/info343/portfolio/#/

Basically if you try clicking on one of the links in the navbar, it'll change it'll turn blue temporarily. If anywhere else on the viewport is clicked, the blue will change back to the black that I want it to be.  Any suggestions as to what is causing this?

This is all I have going on for the navbar in my HTML, the rest is done in CSS:

```
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <nav>
                <ul id="navlist">
                    <li class="navitem"><a class="link" ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="navitem"><a class="link" ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="navitem"><a class="link" ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see what you're having trouble with. Removed my answer as it was inadequate. Edit: posted new answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are CSS conflicts. To debug CSS, you could try the browsers built-in developer tools by pressing F12 or using firebug in Mozilla Firefox.

So, to solve the problem:

```
.navitem a:focus{color:#000;}
```

Comment: Fantastic! I didn't know that a:focus was a thing. Didn't find it listed on any site I looked through. I'll check out the built-in developer tool to debug my CSS next time!

Answer (score 0):

The blue border results from `a:focus` which is defined in bootstrap.css around line 1104:

```
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Overriding the `a:focus` properties for the nav in your css should fix your problem.

```
color: whatever you want;
outline: none;
```